# Expected value of a lognormal random variable formula

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponentiation, expected-value

Given $Z(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$, why does the formula for the expected value of a lognormal random variable, $E(e^{X}) = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}$ give the following:

$$E(e^{\sigma \sqrt{t} Z}) = e^{\sigma ^2  t/2}$$

Since $\sigma = 1$, I thought the calculation would be $E(e^{\sigma \sqrt{t} Z}) = e^{(\sigma   \sqrt{t}) \frac{1}{2} 1^2}$. Can anyone explain how to use the formula correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Your formula states that if $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^X \right] = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}.
$$

In your specific example, if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $\sigma \sqrt{t} Z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^2t\right)$.

Can you now plug into the formula above?

Comment: Thank you for the response, it clarified everything. I didn't consider Var(sigma * sqrt(t) * Z) = sigma^2 * t * Var(Z), because I forgot that t is not a random variable.